# Get datagridview selected row position

Tags: vb.net

I have to open a dialog from datagridview selected row which may be selected by code, by mouse or by keyboard in the position which depends of selected row location.

I get selected row index:

```
Dim srow As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
```

How to easiest get location (XY point) of that selected row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do the code on datagridview cell mouse click event so you will get exact location

```
Private Sub dgvCust_CellMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgvCust.CellMouseClick
    Label1.Text = "X." & e.X & vbCrLf & "Y." & e.Y
End Sub
```